# Control dynamic power management options for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: power-management, battery, tools

I want to test an application to verify (power v/s performance) how it works in different power options available for Ubuntu 16.04. In Ubuntu power management options, I only find `sleep`, `hibernate`, and `power-off`. However, I want more options to work on.

I found that [TLP](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) helps in advanced power management, but TLP works silently in the background and does power management. I really want to keep a power management option each time and check the application performance for the respective mode. Is there any tool that lets me do this.

The application is a cellular network simulator. The performance here is the number of users it serves, throughput, or latency.

Different power modes include power associated when CPU Processor or Frequency scaling, Graphics card, Disk and Controllers, I/O scheduler, shared bus access. By changing some of these parameters (either through command line or any tool) I want to control overall power options (power saving options of Ubuntu).

Comment: What modes do you want to see? What is "power v/s performance"?

Comment: @mikewhatever Edited the question to clarify it further.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking tools to monitoring use:

```
powerstat
```

For reduce power base on profiles i suggest use :

```
pm-utils
```

In ubuntu there is a lot of package and configuration base on your hardware for manage power 
As sample for cpu:

```
cpufreq-selector
```

For graphic card use official document for example lowe power in radeon driver:

echo low | sudo tee /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile 
exit

Also you can tweak hardware base on kernel parameters :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks